# Google Tag Manager Data layer events missing data

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

We've implemented a data layer connection between Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics. Through Custom dimension however, we see over 3.000 events and only 17 records showing the data layer's data. How come there's a lot of missing data and how do you retrieve all event data?

`<script type="text/javascript">
    dataLayer = [];
</script>
<!-- Google Tag Manager (...) /-->`

if user logs in:

`dataLayer.push({
    'fb_id':         response.id,
    'fb_email':      response.email,
    'fb_name':       response.name,
    'fb_first_name': response.first_name,
    'fb_last_name':  response.last_name,
    'fb_gender':     response.gender,
    'fb_link':       response.link,
    'fb_locale':     response.locale,
    'fb_timezone':   response.timezone,
    'event':         'fb_login',
});`

Comment: Could you provide more details and examples of what have you done so far? How did you implemented data layer? how are you pushing it to gtm and when(what event)?

Comment: We push variables to the dataLayer when a user logs in, these variables are defined in a UA-tag in Google Tag Manager. The UA-tag is triggered by pushing 'event':'login' to the dataLayer. So the dayaLayer consist of an event index followed by all variables (which is data connected to the user). 

The GTM event is set to save data to Google Analytics via a custom dimension (tracking session). This custom dimension then shows about 17 records in GA which are part of over 3000 login events.

Comment: It is hard to answer your question if you don't provide minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve    I can now only second guess that maybe you are pushing your event before you push your variables. You need to push variables first, in order for them to be included in datalayer when event is created.

Comment: This is the dataLayer i use:
`dataLayer.push({
         'fb_id':         response.id,
         'fb_email':      response.email,
         'fb_name':       response.name,
         'event':         'fb_login',
        });`

The dataLayer variable is set as an empty array right after opening the body-tag. The GTM-script snippet is just below the empty dataLayer array.

Comment: It looks like "response" is not defined when you fire the event - that would explain why you see the event but not the other data. You can check in browser console if response is defined at all on your page, if it is you might have timing issue => you are firing event before initialising response.

Comment: Just as a note of caution, you should not be sending personally identifiable information into GA, so this includes name, address, and email. Doing so may result in GA terminating your account as you would be in violation of their terms of usage. Also, more to your question, you should install GA Debugger to help you resolve your problem. You can use that to analyse your hits being sent to GA.

Comment: Thank you both, we now make sure all data is collected before the event fires in hope this will resolve our issue.